# rake routes --- LoadError: incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, rake

Any advice on how to fix this?

```
sms-MacBook-Air:myappsm$ rake routes
rake aborted!
LoadError: incompatible library version - /Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:55:in `require_relative'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/Users/sm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sm/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
/Users/sm/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sm/myapp/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/Users/sm/myapp/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sm/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/Users/sm/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Try to uninstall msgpack and rerun `bundle install` after it